# Trying to implement Process Indicator Pattern in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I'm struggling to find a Process Indicator Pattern sample. So far I have a source `STUDENTS` table where I have a `STATUS` field to indicate whether the record was already processed or not. I'm using a task executor for multithreading processing.

In my writer, I'm inserting the processed records to a new `PROCESSED_STUDENTS` table and update the status of the processed records in the source `STUDENTS` table to `Processed`, I'm doing these two operations in a transaction block in case of any failure to revert back the changes.

This is not working with `JdbcPagingItemReader` as some records are left unprocessed at the end of the process.

Can someone please let me know what I'm missing here?

**Reader**

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemReader<SourceData> reader(DataSource dataSource) {
        
    Map<String, Object> parameterValues = new HashMap<>();
    parameterValues.put("status", "ToBeProcessed");     
    
    JdbcPagingItemReader<SourceData> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<>();
    reader.setName("Oracle_RCP");
    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setRowMapper(SourceData.rowMapper());        
    reader.setParameterValues(parameterValues);
    reader.setPageSize(100);        
    reader.setQueryProvider(getQueryProvider(new OraclePagingQueryProvider(), "SELECT ID, NAME, CREATED_TIME", "FROM STUDENTS", "WHERE STATUS = :status", CREATED_TIME, Order.ASCENDING));
    reader.setSaveState(false);     
    
    try {
        reader.afterPropertiesSet();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e.getStackTrace());
    }
    
    return reader;
}

public PagingQueryProvider getQueryProvider(AbstractSqlPagingQueryProvider queryProvider, String select, String from, String where, String sortKey, Order order) {
    queryProvider.setSelectClause(select);
    queryProvider.setFromClause(from);
    
    if (where != null) {
        queryProvider.setWhereClause(where);
    }
    
    Map<String, Order> sortConfiguration = new HashMap<>();
    sortConfiguration.put(sortKey, order);
    queryProvider.setSortKeys(sortConfiguration);
    
    return queryProvider;
}
```

**Processor**

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemProcessor<SourceData, OutData> processor(
        @Value("#{jobParameters['processDate']}") String processDate) {
    return new CustomItemProcessor(processDate);        
}
```

**Writer**

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Bean
public ItemWriter<OutData> writer(Utils utils) {        
    return OutDataList -> utils.batchOperation((List<OutData>) OutDataList, chunk); 
}
```

**Job, Step and TaskExecutor**

```
@Bean("MainJob")
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public Job mainJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, Step step) {        
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("mainJob")   
      .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())          
      .flow(step)
      .end()
      .build();
}

@Bean
public Step step(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {        
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")               
            .<SourceData, OutData> chunk(chunk)
            .reader(reader(null))
            .processor(processor(null))
            .writer(writer(null))   
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
    executor.setCorePoolSize(25);       
    executor.setQueueCapacity(25);
    executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("MultiThreaded-Executor");
    return executor;
}
```

`batchOperation` method used in the Writer to insert the processed records in the `PROCESSED_STUDENTS` table and update the processed records in the `STUDENTS` source table:

```
public void batchOperation(List<OutData> outDataList, int batchSize) {
    try (
            Connection con = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection(); 
            PreparedStatement psInsert = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO PROCESSED_STUDENTS (ID, NAME) VALUES (?, ?)");
            PreparedStatement psUpdate = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE STUDENTS SET STATUS = 'Processed' WHERE ID = ?");) {
        
        // Starting transaction block
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        
        int i = 0;
        for (OutData argument : outDataList) {          
            psInsert.setLong(1, argument.getId());
            psInsert.setString(2, argument.getName());
                        
            psUpdate.setLong(1, argument.getId());
                        
            psInsert.addBatch();
            psUpdate.addBatch();
                        
            i++;
                        
            if (i % batchSize == 0) {
                psInsert.executeBatch();
                psUpdate.executeBatch();
            }               
        }
        
        // Executing remaining batch if total record count is an odd number
        psInsert.executeBatch();
        psUpdate.executeBatch();
        
        // End transaction block, commit changes
        con.commit();

        // Setting it back to default true
        con.setAutoCommit(true);
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 to the answer by @Mar-Z. Also check this sample: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-samples#process-indicator-pattern-sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `JdbcPagingItemReader` in this case because you are changing the parameter used as a filter (status). The pagination won't work.

Simply use `JdbcCursorItemReader` instead.

See also: [(Spring Batch) Not all records are proccessed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76439624/spring-batch-not-all-records-are-proccessed)

Comment: Also configure the ItemReader to NOT save state.  See https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/readers-and-writers/process-indicator.html